# Merge 2 overlap sentences

Tags: python, text, merge

I want to merge to 2 sentences like:

```py
sent1 = 'abcdefghiklmn'
sent2 = 'ziklmopqrst'
```

2 sentences have same *iklm*

```py
result = 'abcdefghiklmnopqrst'
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: need more clarification: you want everything from the first sentence and only the part after intersection in the second sentence right?  As you included "n" from first sentence and missed 'z' from second sentence

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: i use speech to text api to recognition text from video. But it only allows audio < 20s. I split audio such as 0-20s, 15-35s, ... but splitting process can split the middle of word and api will response 2 sentence. the last word of sentence 1 can be different from the first word of sentence 2  and i want to merge them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`difflib.SequenceMatcher`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) comes in handy:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
match = SequenceMatcher(None, sent1, sent2).find_longest_match(0, len(sent1), 0, len(sent2))
result = sent1[:match.a]+sent2[match.b:]
```

Answer (score 2):

maybe this can help

```
sent1 = 'abcdefghiklmn'
sent2 = 'ziklmnopqrst'

for i in sent1:
    n = 0
    for f in sent2:
        n += 1
        if i == f:
            result = sent1 + sent2[n:]
            break

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work :

```
list(set(list("abc")+list("adef")))
```

output is :

```
['a', 'c', 'b', 'e', 'd', 'f']
```

and to convert it to a single string:

```
"".join(['a', 'c', 'b', 'e', 'd', 'f'])
```

output is:

```
'acbedf'
```